# Python: Parse Json to find matching lines matching few keys and return each matching set as single as single json record

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a JSON which looks like below.

```
{"processId":"p1","userId":"user1","reportName":"report1","threadId": "12234", "some_other_keys":"respective values"}
{"userId":"user1","processId":"p1","reportName":"report1","threadId":"12335", "some_other_keys":"respective values"}
{"reportName":"report2","processId":"p1","userId":"user1","threadId":"12434", "some_other_keys":"respective values"}
{"threadId":"12734", "some_other_keys":"respective values", "processId":"p1","userId":"user2","reportName":"report1"}
{"processId":"p1","reportName":"report1","threadId":"12534", "some_other_keys":"respective values","userId":"user2"}
{"processId":"p1","userId":"user1","reportName":"report2","threadId":"12934", "some_other_keys":"respective values"}
{"processId":"p1","userId":"user1","reportName":"report1","threadId":"12834", "some_other_keys":"respective values"}
{"processId":"p1","userId":"user1","reportName":"report2","threadId":"12634", "some_other_keys":"respective values"}
```

**Objective:** write a function that returns all different sets of lines which has the same values of "processId", "userId", "reportName" as a single JSON record with modified key names for each matching records like shown below.

In the above example, there are three matching sets.

Set1 ( for "processId":"p1","userId":"user1","reportName":"report1"):

```
{"processId":"p1","userId":"user1","reportName":"report1","threadId":"12234", "some_other_keys":"respective values"}
{"userId":"user1","processId":"p1","reportName":"report1","threadId":"12335", "some_other_keys":"respective values"}
{"processId":"p1","userId":"user1","reportName":"report1","threadId":"12834", "some_other_keys":"respective values"}
```

Set2 ("processId":"p1","userId":"user1","reportName":"report2"):

```
{"reportName":"report2","processId":"p1","userId":"user1","threadId":"12434", "some_other_keys":"respective values"}
{"processId":"p1","userId":"user1","reportName":"report2","threadId":"12934", "some_other_keys":"respective values"}
{"processId":"p1","userId":"user1","reportName":"report2","threadId":"12634", "some_other_keys":"respective values"}
```

Set3 ("processId":"p1","userId":"user2","reportName":"report2"):

```
{"threadId":"12734", "some_other_keys":"respective values", "processId":"p1","userId":"user2","reportName":"report1"}
{"processId":"p1","reportName":"report1","threadId":"12534", "some_other_keys":"respective values","userId":"user2"}
```

So, in this particular example, the function should return three different sets as below.

Set1 ( for "processId":"p1","userId":"user1","reportName":"report1"):
`{"processId":"p1","userId":"user1","reportName":"report1","threadId_1":"12234", "some_other_keys_1":"respective values", "threadId_2":"12335", "some_other_keys_2":"respective values", "threadId_3":"12834", "some_other_keys_3":"respective values"}`

Set2 ("processId":"p1","userId":"user1","reportName":"report2"):
`{"processId":"p1","userId":"user1","reportName":"report2","threadId_1":"12934", "some_other_keys_1":"respective values","threadId_2":"12434", "some_other_keys_2":"respective values","threadId_3":"12634", "some_other_keys_3":"respective values"}`

Set3 ("processId":"p1","userId":"user2","reportName":"report2"):
`{"threadId_1":"12734", "some_other_keys_1":"respective values", "processId":"p1","userId":"user2","reportName":"report1""threadId_2":"12534", "some_other_keys_2":"respective values"}`

So, one function is returning three sets (this can be more or less also depending on the number of matching sets)

I need a solution for the above problem as a (a) performance efficient code (b) code with a fewer number of lines, as I'll be processing a large number of lines. So want my code to run faster and also the code should be with fewer lines.

Comment: Have you attempted this on your own?

Comment: The provided input JSON is not JSON, please fix it. Aslo, have you tried something yourself?

Comment: Where does the input come from? It is not valid JSON format, so I guess it is a custom format you created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import json

f = open('data.json')
data = json.load(f)
f.close()

sets_of_procces = dict()

for item in data:
    set_id = processId, userId, reportName = item['processId'], item['userId'], item['reportName']
    if set_id not in sets_of_procces.keys():
        sets_of_procces[set_id] = []
    thread_number = len(sets_of_procces[set_id]) + 1
    thread_data = { f'threadId_{thread_number}' : item['threadId'], f'some_other_keys_{thread_number}' : item['some_other_keys'] }
    sets_of_procces[set_id].append(json.dumps(thread_data))

for i, procces_set in enumerate(sets_of_procces):
    print(f'Set {i+1} : \n')
    processId, userId, reportName = procces_set
    json_dict = { 'processId' : processId, 'userId' : userId, 'reportName' : reportName }
    for item in sets_of_procces[procces_set]:
        json_dict = {**json_dict, **json.loads(item)}
    print(json.dumps(json_dict))
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for your answer but **this is not matching my expectation** . 

The expected output is (for one of the sets):
`{"processId":"p1","userId":"user1","reportName":"report1","threadId_1":"12234", "some_other_keys_1":"respective values", "threadId_2":"12335", "some_other_keys_2":"respective values", "threadId_3":"12834", "some_other_keys_3":"respective values"}`
i.e. one json record inside {} for each matching set with modified names for few keys (as _1, _2 etc).

Comment: Here you go @SaurabhChakrabarty